# Generating correlated beta-distributed values in R

Tags: r, statistics, distribution, beta-distribution

I have the written the following code in R with an aim to generate correlated random variables which follow the beta distribution

```
#objective is to generated correlated 
#beta distributed data 

library(MASS)
library(faux)

generate.beta.parameters <- function(x, v) {
  alpha = ((1 - x) / v - 1/ x) * x^2
  beta = alpha * (1 / x - 1)
  return (c(alpha, beta))
}

x1 <- 0.896 
v1 <- 0.001 
x2 <- 0.206 
v2 <- 0.004

b1 <- generate.beta.parameters(x1, v1)
b2 <- generate.beta.parameters(x2, v2)

alpha1 <- b1[1]
beta1 <- b1[2]
alpha2 <- b2[1]
beta2 <- b2[2]


#create mean vector 
mu = c(0, 0)

#create variance covariance matrix 
sigma <- rbind(c(1, 0.2), c(0.2, 1))

#generate 1000 random numbers 
df <- mvrnorm(n = 1000, mu = mu, Sigma = sigma)

df.beta <- matrix(nrow = nrow(df), ncol = ncol(df))
#normal to uniform 
df.beta[,1] = norm2beta(df[,1], alpha1, beta1)
df.beta[,2] = norm2beta(df[,2], alpha2, beta2)

df.beta <- as.data.frame(df.beta)
cor(df.beta)
```

However, on running this code, the correlation outputs are not the same as expected. Here is the output on my machine:

```
          V1        V2
V1 1.0000000 0.1549214
V2 0.1549214 1.0000000
```

Could you throw some light on this?

I do have this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31459291/generate-correlated-random-variables-that-follow-beta-distributions), where random numbers have been generated, but it is in a different software i.e. SAS.

Answer (score 4):

You have two problems. The first is that this is a random sample, so you don't expect the correlation to come out exactly equal to the specified value.  Let's try running 500 samples and see what distribution of correlations we get:

```r
testcor <- function(rho = 0.2, n = 1000, seed = NULL) {
    if (!is.null(seed)) set.seed(seed)
    sigma <- rbind(c(1, rho), c(rho, 1))
    df <- mvrnorm(n = n, mu = mu, Sigma = sigma)
    df.beta <- matrix(nrow = nrow(df), ncol = ncol(df))
    df.beta[,1] = norm2beta(df[,1], alpha1, beta1)
    df.beta[,2] = norm2beta(df[,2], alpha2, beta2)
    cor(df.beta)[1,2]
}
set.seed(101)
corvec <- replicate(500, testcor())
par(las = 1)
hist(corvec, breaks = 50, main ="")
abline(v = 0.2, col = 2, lwd = 2)
```

[image]

The value of 0.155 that you got is toward the lower end of this distribution, but not extreme. Overall the correlation might be biased *slightly* low - the mean is 0.196 - but it looks OK. If you need the simulated correlation to be *exactly* 0.2 for some reason, that will be more challenging - you can set `empirical=TRUE` in `mvrnorm` to get means and variances that exactly match the specified values, but that leads us to the second problem.

---

Feeding the multivariate normal through a nonlinear transformation will change the correlation - not very much in this case (because the distribution of correlations is still centered close to 0.2), but some. This is a mathematical problem, not a programming problem. You've essentially reimplemented a [Gaussian copula model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/87358/how-to-construct-a-multivariate-beta-distribution); you can see in the linked example that the correlations aren't the same as those from the original multivariate normal distribution.

One method for simulating a bivariate distribution with marginal distributions that are Beta and a *specified* correlation is described in Minhajuddin et al 2004 (section 3), but it's significantly more challenging than the approach you've tried here.

The quick-and-dirty way to handle this would be tweak the correlation parameter of the MVN to get the desired correlation of the transformed bivariate Beta ...

---

Minhajuddin, Abu T. M., Ian R. Harris, and William R. Schucany. 2004. “Simulating Multivariate Distributions with Specific Correlations.” Journal of Statistical Computation and Simulation 74 (8): 599–607. https://doi.org/10.1080/00949650310001626161.